# How to initialize data with computed value inside asyncData?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building a web app with nuxt.

here's simplified code:

pages/index.vue

```js
data() {
 return {
  item: {name:'', department: '', testField: '',},
 }
}
async asyncData() {
  const result = call some API

  const dataToInitialize = {
   name: result.username,
   department: result.department,
   testField: //want to assign computed value
  }
  return {item: dataToInitialize}
}
```

Inside asyncData, I call API and assign value to `dataToInitialize`.
`dataToInitialize` has `testField` field, and I want to assign some computed value based on `username` and `department`.
(for example, 'a' if name starts with 'a' and department is 'management'..etc there's more complicated logic in real scenario)

I have tried to use `computed` property , but I realized that asyncData cannnot access computed.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Any help would be appreciated!

=======

not sure if it's right way, but I solved the issue by setting 'testfield' inside created.

```js
created() {
    this.item.testField = this.someMethod(this.item);
},
```

Comment: `created` should be called after `asyncData`, is it working as expected?

Comment: it's working as expected. I first initialize data with asyncData, then overwrites testField field inside created so the data was correctly displayed. I will try the method that you suggested.(using fetch) @kissu

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Nuxt lifecyle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client), you can see that `asyncData` is called before even a Vue instance is mounted on your page.
Meanwhile, `fetch()` hook is called after. This is non-blocking but more flexible in a lot of ways.

An alternative using `fetch()` would look like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      staticVariable: 'google',
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    await this.$axios(this.computedVariable)
  },
  computed: {
    computedVariable() {
      return `www.${this.staticVariable}.com`
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Another alternative, would be to use URL query string or params, thanks to Vue-router and use those to build your API call (in an `asyncData` hook).
Here is an example on how to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68112290/8816585

---

EDIT after comment question
You can totally use a `computed` inside of a `fetch()` hook indeed. Here is an example on how to achieve this

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: 'test',
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.nice}`)
    console.log(await response.json())
  },
  computed: {
    nice() {
      return this.test + 'wow!'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using fetch() as you suggested and I could see that I can use computed value inside fetch. One problem though. Inside fetch, I replaced this line`return {item: dataToInitialize}`, with `this.item=dataToInitialize` but `this.item` that's supposed to displayed on the page is blank. 
I use component and pass `this.item` as a prop to this child component.
Is that because child component is created and mounted before fetch is done?

Comment: I've edited my answer, even tho I'm not sure of you do want exactly. Also, this link may maybe help, to see how the whole thing is mounted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319825/8816585 And here is Nuxt's lifecycle: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle @amu03

Answer (score 0):

I found that destructuring `fetch({})` causes issues with accessing `this` inside fetch scope ->

```
async fetch({ store, $anyOtherGlobalVar }){ 
store.dispatch... 
// destructuring approach changes the scope of the function and `this` does not have access to data, computed and e.t.c
}
```

If you want to access `this` scope for example `this.data`, avoid destructuring and access everything through `this.`

```
async fetch() {
 this.$store...
 this.data...
}
```